# Is $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)^{h}$ an elementary substructure of/existentially closed in $\mathbb{F}_{p}((t))$?

Tags: model-theory, fields, valuation-theory, decidability

It is a well-known fact that the Henselization of the function field $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ in regard to the $t$-adic valuation is $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)^{alg} \cap \mathbb{F}_{p}((t))$, so of course $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)^{h}$ embeds into $\mathbb{F}_{p}((t))$, but is it known whether this embedding is elementary in the language of rings $\mathcal{L}_{\text{Ring}}$ or respectively the language of valued fields $\mathcal{L}_{\text{Ring}, \ \mid}$ (this does not matter as the valuation is uniformly definable in henselian valued fields with finite residue field). I would assume that, if this is true, it is not known because we do not know whether $\mathbb{F}_{p}((t))$ is decidable, but do we at least know whether $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)^{h}$ is existentially closed in $\mathbb{F}_{p}((t))$? This  at least should be guaranteed for the perfect hull by Ax-Kochen-Ershov for tame fields.

Comment: I actually found an answer to my question in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0194.pdf Theorem 5.12. I will try to digest this in an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: It was recently claimed by Rideau-Scanlon that indeed $\mathbb{F}_p(t)^h \preceq \mathbb{F}_p((t))$, although there is no arXiv preprint yet (see http://www.math.ens.fr/-Seminaires-?id_seance=764).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is apparently not a very short answer to this. It is, I think, really not known whether this extension is elementary and it would be very surprising if it was known, since we do not even know if the theory of $\mathbb{F}_{p}((t))$ is decidable. But there is the following result by Franz-Viktor Kuhlmann in his paper "The Algebra and Model Theory of Tame Valued Fields" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0194.pdf, Theorem 5.9)

> Let $(K,v)$ be a henselian field. Assume that $(L/K,v)$ is a separable subextension of $(K^{c}/K,v)$. Then $(K,v)$ is existentially closed in $(L,v)$. In particular, every henselian inseparable defectless field is existentially closed in its completion.

Here $K^{c}$ stands for the completion in regard to $v$. Now we take a look at $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)^{h}$, it is obviously henselian. And from that it obviously follows that any henselian valued field is existentially closed in its completion. Of course this does not give a lot of insight on the problem, so let me try and elaborate a little: The proof of Theorem 5.9 makes use of the fact that it is enough to be existentially closed in every finitely generated subfield to be existentially closed. So we take such a subfield $(F,v)$ and go over to its Henselization, which still lies in the completion (because the completion is Henselian). This is of course a subextension hence it is separable. We can see that indeed $(F,v)^{h}=(K(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}),v)^{h}$. Then it boils down to show that if we set $K_{i}:=(K(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{i}), v)^{h}$, then $K_{i} \leq_{1} K_{i+1}$, which we can show by realizing that $x$ is the limit of a Cauchy sequence and further results in the linked paper.

This is of course a very rough sketch. It is better to read the paper to grasp the proof in detail.

Comment: You might also be interested in this paper if you haven't already seen it: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.04522.pdf. Their results show that all Henselian valued fields of equicharacteristic $p$ and residue field $\mathbb{F}_p$ have the same existential theory, and that the existential theory of $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ is decidable.

Comment: Yes, thank you for that comment! I learned of the paper in the mean time, but it is good that it is mentioned here!